# Remove redundant intersections when flattening a complex record

Tags: typescript, static-typing, typescript-types

I have a complex `Flattened` type that gives me a result that is right for me.
However the resulting type has a lot of duplicate intersections when, in the input record:

1. A key is isolated (in the example the key `d`)
2. The corresponding value is a union

```js
type Primitive = number | string | boolean | Date;

export type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never;

export type Flattened<T, Sep extends string> = T extends
  | Primitive
  | unknown[]
  | Record<string, Primitive | unknown[]>
  ? T
  : T extends Record<string, unknown>
  ? UnionToIntersection<
      {
        [K in keyof T & string]: Flattened<T[K], Sep> extends infer Flat
          ? Flat extends Primitive | unknown[]
            ? { [P in K]: T[P] }
            : Flat extends Record<string, unknown>
            ? {
                [KFlat in keyof Flat &
                  string as `${K}${Sep}${KFlat}`]: Flat[KFlat];
              }
            : Flat extends unknown
            ? { [KFlat in K]: Flat }
            : never
          : never;
      }[keyof T & string]
    >
  : T extends unknown
  ? T
  : never;


type ComplexA = "complexA1" | "complexA2";
type ComplexB = "complexB1" | "complexB2" | "complexB3";


/**
 * Expected type: 
 * {
 *     a_b: ComplexA;
 * } & {
 *     c_d: ComplexB;
 * } & {
 *     d: ComplexB;
 * }
 *
 *
 * Actual type: 
 * {
 *     a_b: ComplexA;
 * } & {
 *     c_d: ComplexB;
 * } & {
 *     d: ComplexB;
 * } & {
 *     d: ComplexB;
 * } & {
 *     d: ComplexB;
 * }
 */
Flattened<
{
  a: { b: ComplexA };
  c: { d: ComplexB };
  d: ComplexB;
}, '_'
>
```

[Here's a link to a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAdgVyQCMI4oAfKAZ2EVwHMKoiB7FgGwgENcmARLsAgBuAFCiIADzAs4wKKEhQAqrgQtcAFRYBJXELhUIAYzQaAPMoB8ULKKhQA9I6gQq7BPoC0AEwRUuIk4vXClgLw9QqAABRTdjRDBwt0jgR1wWLykwD2NULx4QeygACmVXSSFcHyooQqgAflKAawAuFQBKWxt0FgQfKHbQzDgusIhq2pK2qE8AM1IoHS6sHr6fYocmnU3BvAgRsQlpWXk4qAAxdkEqiB9zTQAaKABlCDAKqprqWk96Gxwmk+ExqxUo8GQqAwEDBUHwuGaGQA7rgANoAXVhACUTLJ7jQ6PRnhCUGhMEx4YiWCiMVZik1NMV2kDxpMoDjjHjzAS-s9KcjcHStio1BptHoDEZTOpcOZdg4AN7yhxQVEAaVmvGaEBALDmUCBADIfoT0e0rjcJncHur0c83mAbKzvvNFhbgMqVY1Ltd5M7aiSoeTKPzqWjMV7IyqmgrVTBNVA1WaDaiYOioABfT2R82+4FsjlcnkMPkIgVCqORmPZyuqtXuhPa3X6huGmu1k1-Oq1AAGABIFWqMwOHcPB+6Mz3k+71e70WIO5Gs4uHLnBPnvqGUe3hbHZ3nPInp3nlyuhgdSO3z4dlRnUU29QaoMbi-QIyqK8yN7Ut7h6QamX2G9jhkOQoDmeFpQ0cDfSqAB5IgACs5QcODv3ZXE4HxX4SzhMswysR5ijg-A-UqEFandW57jg+13kI4oHXQ19bCgAAiAB9NjRCsEpihYJD2lo4ojDAdomJwTi2O7V53iIhwwC4OAJmAeAWDAAA5LgkAgdoWMoAh2HYVjDPYeSoGUqh2hgJS0C4dhzBI4AASgBUsw6ITSNc4o5lkUpOVwGgoCbBMBMQrolS9BB9RKMKADoAAsuCoOCUTUyA5BAaYdQ6CLlQCoKwDgdStJ01jFOU-R0tK6Amn7BUKpU6rtIgMdRLHJtJz2JsF0jaLSjiR8wvvHV0ywcb2LCkxgDYvLazmWCJgQxDYqQkaQHTZKMM5LDuRwok8KpFFCOoOSoCKkqWueSyOl6r0M1cdgjG82tLNRC7NJamSH31JyxqgYam02n98JRGSnPWx8-rulVTwcU9T2U4B8DgXhLPB0ixCzURzgAYRYJAcikABBVi2M5QnOEkYmAEZpMocmCaJ6mACY2LEPGmapgAhMmKeZ7m6aYRnKakbm2eF-meYAZnZ8QCvkTwwFI9olS4VXmHafHRepzMxGMDWfC1rmxb10QjagbWBax1i1dV3YiHaEXmdptiiIzIiDZelULednm6fdojfalsW2fdo5HAAKkj+xI6gABRaRpruBRwF0qBY5euOvS4DjHctk3qYXOOHuNSLs5VYwOItq2eeLzNnyzyMa8L7n6+XSPHFEBW6lMfB7NYhbLVwZaSiV0jbtEIA) that also contains an implementation for a `flatten` function.

Comment: I'll do ya one better and flatten the intersection to a single type: https://tsplay.dev/mbQOoN

Comment: Wow that's grand! Do you think the UnionToIntersection is still relevant with your technique?

Comment: You would still need to use it to turn the resulting union into an intersection, so I think you would still need it.

Comment: Gotcha. I noticed that when input attributes were optional, optional keys would become required. So I modified the algorithm to make keys optional for values that can be undefined: https://tsplay.dev/WKOM8W